# JSON Multidimensional Array to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have a condition that require me to make a html table using json multidimensional.
This is the sample of my JSON Data

```
let year = [
  {
    ym : "202006",
    data : [
       {
         202007: "100", 
         202008: "100", 
         202009: "100", 
         202010: "100", 
         202011: "96.71", 
         202012: "100", 
         202101: "100", 
         202102: "96.43"
       }
    ]
  }
];
```

And this is my expected result

[image]

I already managed to create the table header using loop. But i find it difficult when generating table data using this JSON Data.
Any kind of help will be really appriciated . Thank you

**EDIT :**

I was able to generate the table header using original data .
The code i was using is

```
result = arr.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.TIME_PERIOD_HEADER] = r[a.TIME_PERIOD_HEADER] || [];
    r[a.TIME_PERIOD_HEADER].push(a);
    return r;
}, Object.create(null));

var keys = Object.keys(result);

keys.map((value, index) => {
  $('#tbl_row').append('<th>'+value+'</th>')
})
```

After i generated the table header, i tried to modify the original json array into a new json array using :

```
var o = arr.reduce( (a,b) => {
  a[b.TIME_PERIOD] = a[b.TIME_PERIOD] || [];
  a[b.TIME_PERIOD].push({[b.TIME_PERIOD_DATA]:b.PERCENT});
  return a;
}, {});

var a = Object.keys(o).map(function(k) {
  var m = Object.assign.apply({},o[k]);
    keys.forEach( (x) => { if ( !(x in m) ) m[x] = 0 });
    
    return {TIME_PERIOD: k, TIME_PERIOD_DATA: m};
});
//this code produce the first JSON data (let year = ....)
```

Comment: Can you please post your code that's generating the header and anything you've tried to generate the body? Otherwise, we can only guess why your code to generate the body is failing.

Comment: if you can create the header, the single line of data is basically the same loop - probably easier, since you'd be working with values rather than keys

Comment: @mkaatman i already did

Comment: @JaromandaX i create the header using the original data, before it was modified to let year = ....

Comment: Your expected output shows only one row per `ym`. But `data` is an array. This does not match.

Comment: @ceving i tried to use <td> to make data into row , and using 202007-202102 as index to loop the array data . but it's a complete failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet ignores that `data` is an array, because your expected output ignores it, too.

```js
let year = [
  {
    ym : "202006",
    data : [
       {
         202007: "100", 
         202008: "100", 
         202009: "100", 
         202010: "100", 
         202011: "96.71", 
         202012: "100", 
         202101: "100", 
         202102: "96.43"
       }
    ]
  }
];

let columns = year
  .map (y => y.data)
  .flat (1)
  .map (d => Object.keys(d))
  .flat (1)
  .sort ()
  .filter ((x, i, a) => !i || x != a[i-1]);

document.write ('<table><tdata>');
document.write ('<tr style="text-transform: uppercase">');
document.write ('<th rowspan="2">time period</th>');
document.write (`<th colspan=${columns.length}>time period data</th>`);
document.write ('</tr></tr>');
for (const c of columns) {
  document.write (`<td>${c}</td>`);
}
document.write ('</tr>');
for (const y of year) {
  document.write (`<tr><td>${y.ym}</td>`);
  for (const c of columns) {
    document.write (`<td>${y.data[0][c]}</td>`);
  }
  document.write ('</tr>');
}
document.write ('<tdata><table>');
```

The idea is: iterated over all your data to calculate the column list. After that iterate over the years and for each year iterate over the columns to pick the right value from the data for the column. The filter after the sort makes the sorted list unique, because the code collects all columns from all data objects.

Comment: Thank you, this really solved my case . i was trying to make a pivot table from the query . it's a much more easy solution . but it's much more harder to do it in query .